# Forecasting timeseries data

Tags: r, date, time-series, forecasting

```
           **Point Forecast     Lo 80    Hi 80       Lo 95    Hi 95 account
2017.4137        180.8861 103.03618 258.7361  61.8249012 299.9474  R00172
2017.4164        181.3260 102.63465 260.0173  60.9779946 301.6739  R00172
2017.4192        181.7658 102.24090 261.2906  60.1429756 303.3886  R00172
2017.4219        182.2056 101.85468 262.5565  59.3194730 305.0917  R00172
2017.4247        182.6454 101.47575 263.8151  58.5071341 306.7837  R00172
2017.4274        183.0852 101.10391 265.0665  57.7056233 308.4648  R00172**
```

The following output is as follows
my requirement is to convert this `2017.4137,2017.4164,2017.4192.........`
  into Date format.

```
 esw<-rownames(df2)
> esw
  [1] "2017.4137"   "2017.4164"   "2017.4192"   "2017.4219"   "2017.4247"   "2017.4274"  
  [7] "2017.4301"   "2017.4329"   "2017.4356"   "2017.4384"   "2017.4411"   "2017.4438"  
 [13] "2017.4466"   "2017.4493"   "2017.4521"   "2017.4548"   "2017.4575"   "2017.4603"  
 [19] "2017.4630"   "2017.4658"   "2017.4685"   "2017.4712"   "2017.4740"   "2017.4767"  
 [25] "2017.4795"   "2017.4822"   "2017.4849"   "2017.4877"   "2017.4904"   "2017.4932"
```

iam not able to get the date format

```
df2$dates<-as.Date(esw,format="%Y/%m/%d")

df2$dates<-as.Date(esw,format="%Y/%m/%d")

> df2$dates
  [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [31] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [61] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [91] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Iam getting all NA's. 
Can anybody please help me how to proceed further?

Thanks

Comment: where are you getting your dates from?

Comment: The format argument is to describe the format of the input, not the output. And I don't get the input: is it a fraction of a year ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to transform esw into a datetime format using lubridate:

```
esw <- c("2017.4137",   "2017.4164",   "2017.4192" ,  "2017.4219",   "2017.4247",   "2017.4274",  
                 "2017.4301",   "2017.4329",   "2017.4356" ,  "2017.4384" ,  "2017.4411" ,  "2017.4438",  
                  "2017.4466",   "2017.4493",   "2017.4521",   "2017.4548",   "2017.4575" ,  "2017.4603" , 
                  "2017.4630",   "2017.4658",   "2017.4685" ,  "2017.4712" ,  "2017.4740" ,  "2017.4767" , 
                  "2017.4795",   "2017.4822",   "2017.4849" ,  "2017.4877" ,  "2017.4904" ,  "2017.4932")
esw <- as.numeric(esw)
library(lubridate)
format(date_decimal(esw), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

 [1] "2017-06-01 00:00:43" "2017-06-01 23:39:50" "2017-06-03 00:11:31" "2017-06-03 23:50:38" "2017-06-05 00:22:19"
 [6] "2017-06-06 00:01:26" "2017-06-06 23:40:33" "2017-06-08 00:12:14" "2017-06-08 23:51:21" "2017-06-10 00:23:02"
[11] "2017-06-11 00:02:09" "2017-06-11 23:41:16" "2017-06-13 00:12:57" "2017-06-13 23:52:04" "2017-06-15 00:23:45"
[16] "2017-06-16 00:02:52" "2017-06-16 23:41:59" "2017-06-18 00:13:40" "2017-06-18 23:52:47" "2017-06-20 00:24:28"
[21] "2017-06-21 00:03:35" "2017-06-21 23:42:43" "2017-06-23 00:14:23" "2017-06-23 23:53:31" "2017-06-25 00:25:11"
[26] "2017-06-26 00:04:19" "2017-06-26 23:43:26" "2017-06-28 00:15:07" "2017-06-28 23:54:14" "2017-06-30 00:25:55"
```

If you only want dates and no time, be careful because the year fractions can lead to duplicate dates. In this case, June 1 2017

```
format(date_decimal(esw), "%Y-%m-%d")
 [1] "2017-06-01" "2017-06-01" "2017-06-03" "2017-06-03" "2017-06-05" "2017-06-06" "2017-06-06" "2017-06-08" "2017-06-08"
[10] "2017-06-10" "2017-06-11" "2017-06-11" "2017-06-13" "2017-06-13" "2017-06-15" "2017-06-16" "2017-06-16" "2017-06-18"
[19] "2017-06-18" "2017-06-20" "2017-06-21" "2017-06-21" "2017-06-23" "2017-06-23" "2017-06-25" "2017-06-26" "2017-06-26"
[28] "2017-06-28" "2017-06-28" "2017-06-30"
```

Comment: It is working,I thankful to you for your suggestion Sir

Comment: And i had a small doubt in the above esw<-c("2017.4137",   "2017.4164")these two are different but in your output you got the same dates as "2017-06-01" "2017-06-01",(in the same way all dates are repeated), May i know what is the problem?Is there any wrong with format  command which we used above.

Comment: @eswar If you look at the first part of the answer, I show that "2017.4137",   "2017.4164" correspond to "2017-06-01 00:00:43" "2017-06-01 23:39:50".  they are both on the same date but at different times. If you don't look at the time, it falls on the same date.